# Intermolecular forces in Carbon Nanotubes?

Tags: intermolecular-forces, nanotechnology

What are the intermolecular forces that can be found in Carbon Nanotubes?

Comment: I am unfortunately not really getting what you are asking. Are you asking about the bonds between the carbons, or the forces that are inside a nanotube, or are you asking about the molecular forces between nanotubes? It would not hurt if you could expand your question a little.

Comment: The intermolecular forces between the molecules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is known, but poorly understood [$\pi-\pi$ stacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacking_(chemistry)). While weak compared to covalent, dipole or ionic interactions, it still beats usual van-der-vaals interactions.

Carbon nanotubes are, essentially, polycondensed aromatical systems, so they can and would interact with each other as aromatic systems via $\pi-\pi$ stacking

Comment: To be fair, $\pi-\pi$ stacking are often considered one type of **dispersion** interactions. Since large conjugated systems like nanotubes have very high polarizabilities, the dispersion interactions are fairly large.

Answer (score 3):

Carbon nanotubes are not polar or ionic.  Therefore I do not expect any ion or dipole intermolecular interactions.  Since carbon has electrons, that only leaves us with dispersion forces (induced-dipole).  Therefore carbon nanotubes exhibit **dispersion** as the only intermolecular force.